# Class Does Not Exist, ReflectionError

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-5, composer-php

I changed my folder structure and namespaces in my project.  Previously I used the following namespace in my controllers:

```
App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\
```

I changed my folder structure and changed all my namespaces to

```
App\Http\FrontEnd\Controllers\
```

I run:

```
composer self-update
```

Then I run:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Finally I run:

```
composer update
```

Everything updated successfully then at the end of it all I get this error:

```
[ReflectionException]
Class App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\Auth\AuthController does not exist
```

The only think I can think of is that I forgot to change something somewhere important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in your project file usages of `AuthController`. You said that you change folder structure to `App\Http\FrontEnd\Controllers\` and as you see for `AuthController` you get error `App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\Auth\AuthController` so probably somewhere in your code you have: `Auth\AuthController:...`

Comment: Done, found it in my routes.php file, also since i was using multiple namespaces i had to go and remove the default namespace in the RouteServiceProvider